# Validation Rule text field required when multi-picklist value is selected

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to have a text field required when a value is selected in Multi-picklist field

```
IF(
    AND(TEXT(Environment_Access__c ) = "DevQA", 
        ISBLANK( Business_Justification__c )), 
    True,
    False
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with just `condition`.

Second, you need to use `INCLUDES` rather than `TEXT`.

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist__c, "SingleOption"),
    ISBLANK(Other_Field__c)
)
```

Comment: That worked i appreciate it

Comment: @vanessa If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 0):

For checking a value in multi select picklist, you will have to use `INCLUDES`

Your validation rule should be like this

```
IF(AND(INCLUDES(Environment_Access__c, 'DevQA'), ISBLANK(Business_Justification__c)), true, false)
```

Or

```
AND(INCLUDES(Environment_Access__c, 'DevQA'), ISBLANK(Business_Justification__c))
```

You can check this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) for further help.